# WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 Switch Mediator Case matching not working

Tags: regex, wso2, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1. I need to check if a particular field exists in the Incoming Payload XML. If Iit does, a Switch Case should run, otherwise it should run a default scenario. The field on which I am checking will always have a dynamic value and it would look like following:

```
20000569899
```

I wrote following logic in ESB:

```
 <property name="CheckIdExist" expression="//*[local-name()='Id']" scope="default" type="STRING" description="CheckIdExist"/>
    <switch source="get-property('CheckIdExist')">
        <case regex="[a-zA-Z0-9]">
            <sequence key="SequenceA"/>
            <sequence key="SequenceB"/>
            <sequence key="SequenceC"/>
        </case>
        <default>
           <log></log>
        </default>
    </switch>
```

**Problem:**

The problem is that Switch is able to pick a value from the property but it does not match the Case regular expression. Following are some ESB Logs Entries:

**Logs Entries:**

```
XPath : get-property('CheckIdExist') evaluates to : 20001089900

None of the switch cases matched - executing default
```

I checked online, this regular expression works. So what i am unable to understand is that why WSO2 ESB is not recognizing it as a valid expression. Or is there any other way to check that if a field exists in an input request then a particular switch case should work, Otherwise not.

Comment: Try  `<case regex="[a-zA-Z0-9]+">`.

Comment: Great it worked........ Thanks.. Please post it as answer so i can mark it Green.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression lacks a [quantifier `+`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) meaning *1 or more occurrences*:

```
<case regex="[a-zA-Z0-9]+">
```